# VB.net result for x base

Tags: vb.net-2010

This is my first question and I am new to vb.net and programming I am trying to build the simple xbase calculation like if I had 2 eggs value 2 dollars so 3 eags value calculated by the program.

I did this code but the answer never show up in the Textbox4

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim a As Integer
        a = TextBox1.Text
        Dim b As Integer
        b = TextBox2.Text
        Dim c As Integer
        c = TextBox3.Text
        Dim d As Integer
        d = TextBox4.Text
        TextBox4.Text = b * c / a


    End Sub
End Class
```

I want Textbox4 automatically show result when i put the values.

Answer (score 1):

Add a button to the form and move the code the click event handler for the button.  When the form loads, those textboxes are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in the Form load event.  There is no way to enter stuff into the textboxes before the code executes.  You can either add a button and use its click event, or textchanged events when you enter stuff into the textboxes.